# Is there a way to run tests from shared components folder from angular project with angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

I have an angular 7 app, consisting of two projects and one component library, used by the projects. In this library with shared components there are some tests(spect.ts) files. Is there a way to run tests from shared library when I run tests in either of my projects(ng test --project project1 or ng test --project project2)?

My folder structure:

`app
 - node_modules
 - projects
   - project1
   - project1-e2e
   - project2
   - project2-e2e
   - shared`

I forgot to add that this shared components library wasn't created with angular-cli, therefore it wasn't added to angular.json file and doesn't have build or test config options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from your `package.json` in the root of your project.

In the `scripts` section add a script that runs both of these tests.

e.g.

`"test-all": "ng test my-main-project && ng test my-library"`

For clarification, the names to use for your `my-main-project` and `my-library` can be found in your `angular.json` file in the `projects` object.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this shared library is not included in angular.json file

Comment: Could you provide more info about where you get this library from? Is this 3rd party, hows it built usually etc.?

Comment: It's just a created manually folder, where shareable components were placed. I presume this is not the right way to create such libraries? I've googled and found out that support for shareable libraries was added to angular-cli. This is probably how this library project should have been created at the first place.

Comment: Yes, it is recommended that you use the angular-cli to create shared libraries. Much more tooling support. This is available from Angular v6+.

This way you have more control over building / testing. Furthermore if you need to publish to npm, the libraries make it possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As we figured out in the comments section: the best way to create libraries with shared elements in Angular 6+ apps is to use angular-cli and command ng generate library .
With that you also have a config added to your angular.json file with everything set up for running your tests, located in your shared library.